# Like statement in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I am new to marklogic and not really sure how to write a like statement in marklogic query...Can anyone please tell me how to write a Like statement( same as sql)  in marklogic query? I want to pass a parameter string to the function and want all strings as an output which contains parameter string..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried? Have you looked at the syntax and examples in the user guide at https://docs.marklogic.com/sql:like ? Have you tried searching through the other questions tagged with marklogic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marklogic

Comment: I think an example would help. Usually LIKE is very inefficient in relational databases and used when other techniques would be better.  For example, people often people use LIKE to do word matching, and MarkLogic has much better text match libraries. Sometimes people use LIKE to match substrings in tokens, and for that MarkLogic has wildcards.

Comment: Thanks...just gone through the marklogic references and found the answer...we can use cts:element-value-query("tagName", "\*textToSearch\*",("wildcard")... This worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to query data in MarkLogic but I am going to assumeCTS or SPARQL.

CTS https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.wordQuery

```
cts.search(
    cts.wordQuery("MarkLogic Cor?oration*",
                   [""wildcarded""]));
```

SPARQL

```
select ?s ?p ?o
where{
  ?s ?p ?o 
     filter contains(?o,"New South")
     .filter regex(?o,"New")
}
limit 10
```

I have given both the contains and regular expression but have found regular expression works faster,